# `Vue is not defined` error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a vue project via vue cli 3. To structure  my code, I made a dir called common where I keep files with .js ext. So, I transferred some code from my .vue file which was in views folder and surprisingly it did not work.

I imported Vue like `import Vue from 'vue';` and set a debugger. When I hover over the `Vue`, it says undefined. I even imported my custom js file to check and same issue there too.

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.3",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.12",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

## common/apiService.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { API_URL } from '@/common/config';
import axios from 'axios';

const ApiService = {
  init() {
    debugger
    axios.defaults.baseURL = API_URL;
  },

  get(resource, slug = '') {
    return axios
      .get(`${resource}/${slug}`)
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(`[PTE] ApiService ${error}`);
      });
  },

  post(resource, params) {
    debugger
    return axios.post(`${resource}`, params);
  },
};

export default ApiService;
```

please note that i have imported Vue but have not used it. Will use it later after i fix this issue.

Comment: Note that some build processes may remove "unused" variables, what happens when you print out `Vue` using `console.log`

Comment: Ferrybig is right, most likely your build process has removed Vue since it's never being used. Try assigning it to something, like `window.vue = Vue`, and see if `window.vue` is undefined.

Comment: What happens if you try importing `vue` from `vue/dist/vue`?